# Multiple particle systems are glitching all over the place?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, eevee-render-engine

Ok, Im in Blender 2.8 if that makes a difference but the main issue is getting multiple smoke simulations to work in the same scene. Since this is 2.8 Ive looked at past questions like [Is it possible to have more than one smoke simulation in the same scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-smoke-simulation-in-the-same-scene) , however some settings are different and I dont think I set up my smoke in the same way.

This came from an example project, but each smoke sim is just a plane that is an emitter, with a metaball as the emission object.

One was completely fine, and Ive tried sticking the 3 different emitters in different Collections (because the SO answers say to separate layers), but even when I turn off visibility on 2/3 emitters, the one remaining glitches out.

By glitching out I mean that it runs, but the smoke glitches locations like this:

[image]
[image]

I had a domain originally, but even setting to scale around all emitters, and even deleting it, does nothing. I just have the particle emitter and the domain cube, and Im not sure they're interacting.

What am I doing wrong? If these are just emitters, why are they glitching locations?

[image: s]

The metaballs themselves are moving locations.

Comment: I do not find the question to be clear. Please clarify the question.  Perhaps other people do find it to be clear.  [Glitching] as you use the word,  above is a vague term.  Please show one system that succeeds and label it clearly.  Please show the scenario that fails and label it clearly.  Please explain the difference between the two. Consider hiding any objects any objects that are not relevant to the problem.  I cannot guess what is success and failure in your images ... I must be told clearly by you.

Comment: You wrote SO... what is that?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger stack overflow. The 3 images were to show, in progression, the changing location of the particle systems/meta ball aggregates. They glitch, meaning they flicker back and forth between different locations all over the scene